# any app or script to download wallpapers from different websites

Tags: software-recommendation, desktop-background

I have found an app Love Wallpapers HD, which working in `ubuntu-tweak`, it is good but there is no settings or option in that app.

But I need an app which can change wallpaper and also download from different websites, like Tumblr or Deviantart.  Or if there might be a script which can do that.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[Variety](http://peterlevi.com/variety/) is exactly what you're asking for.

[image: variety-screenshot]

To install it,

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:peterlevi/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install variety
```

Comment: Hi, Zuhaib
i have acutally tried this but it does not get the wallpaper from tumblr or deviantart

Comment: Variety supports Media RSS feeds. deviantART provides such feeds directly - read here: http://www.deviantart.com/developers/rss, or just open any deviantART category, view the page source and search for "rss". For tumblr you can use a feed generator such as http://tumb.la/mrss/generator.html to get a Media RSS feed.